# Why does this timezone correct the daylight savings time

Tags: c#, timezone

Daylight savings for Eastern Standard Time 2016 starts on 3/13/2016 @ 2am. At which time the clocks get set back to 1am, making the 2am hour invalid.

This code block reports an error for the 2am hour for the dateTime2 var.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo1;
timeZoneInfo1 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var dateTime1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2016, 3, 13, 1, 0, 0), timeZoneInfo1);
var dateTime2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2016, 3, 13, 2, 0, 0), timeZoneInfo1);        //Reports invalid date error
var dateTime3 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2016, 3, 13, 3, 0, 0), timeZoneInfo1);
```

However, in the below example for the time zone "Pacific SA Standard Time", daylight saving for 1990 starts on 10/13/1990@11pm. This should make the dateTime4 10/13/1990@11pm an invalid date/time.

Instead, the dateTime4 returns as valid date/time.

Also, dateTime5 returns as 10/14/1990@1am, automatically skipping the midnight hour.

And dateTime6 returns as 10/14/1990@2am instead of 1am as I expected.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo2;
timeZoneInfo2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific SA Standard Time");
var dateTime4 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(1990, 10, 13, 23, 0, 0), timeZoneInfo2);      //10-14-1990@11pm
var dateTime5 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(1990, 10, 14, 0, 0, 0), timeZoneInfo2);       //10-14-1990@1am
var dateTime6 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(1990, 10, 14, 1, 0, 0), timeZoneInfo2);       //10-14-1990@2am
```

What is the reason for the two ways the TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime works?

I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- `Pacific SA Standard Time` is the ID for the Windows time zone having the English display name `(UTC-03:00) Santiago`.  That's Santiago, Chile.
- The earliest entry in Windows for this time zone is for 2007.  It does not have data for 1990, and thus erroneously assumes anything before 2007 is the same as 2007.  In general, Microsoft time zones do not have an extensive history.

  - See the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), which has a section titled "The Microsoft Time Zone Database".  It describes how they work, where you can see their details in the registry, and the pros and cons of using them.
- Chile has a rich history of varying DST dates from year to year.  [See here for year-to-year details from that period](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/chile/santiago?syear=1989).
- [In 1990, DST started on September 16th at 12:00 AM](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/chile/santiago?year=1990).  The hour from 12:00 to 1:00 AM was skipped.  Not October 13th from 11:00 PM to 12:00 PM as you suggested.
- If historical accuracy is important to your application, then do not use Windows time zone identifiers or the `TimeZoneInfo` class.  They are not up for that particular task.  Instead, use IANA identifiers (such as `America/Santiago` or `America/New_York`), and use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  There are many other advantages to using Noda Time as well.
- To answer the last two questions, `dateTime5` and `dateTime6` are created without specifying `DateTimeKind`, so they have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` by default.  Then, when you call the `ConvertTime` function, per the remarks [in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb382835.aspx), the value is assumed to have originated in your *local* time zone.

  To be clear, your code is converting these dates *from* your local time zone, *to* the time zone you specify.

  So, if those dates were valid in your *local* time zone (whatever that may be), then they can indeed be converted and won't throw an exception.  If the results are an hour different, then that means your local time zone is an hour off from what Windows thinks Santiago was at that time.